assignment to struct member where RHS reads whole struct
Consider a pretty standard struct definition:
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  int crc;
  int c;
};

and initalization
  s.a = 1; 
  s.b = 2;
  s.c = 3;
  // spec says crc is computed over whole struct with crc field set to 0
  s.crc = 0;

  s.crc = crc32(&s, sizeof(s));

The question concerns the last statement. The RHS of course does not modify s, so it's not quite a i = i++ situtation. Still, I'm unsure if this is technically undefined behaviour, and whether it would have to be written using a temporary
 crc = crc32(&s, sizeof(s));
 s.crc = crc;

One somewhat absurd scenario I can think of would be the compiler having to spill some register prior to calling the crc32 function, seeing that 'hey, s.crc is going to be updated anyway', so instead of using a stack slot, it would use s.crc. That is, essentially do
  mov regX, s.crc
  call crc32()
  mov s.crc, regX
  mov regA, s.crc

The C standard says (C99, 6.5.16.1.3): "If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way
the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall
have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.". But the value being stored here is not directly read from another object, but computed by reading from another (super)object.

The code is well defined but conceptually very bad.


if this is technically undefined behaviour

It is not undefined behavior, it's ok.
After a function is executed, there is a sequence point.

The C standard says (C99, 6.5.16.1.3)

Not applicable here, the code is storing the result of a function call, which is a temporary object, not a real object with storage.
The https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7 could be mentioned, so crc32 should only use "a character type" for example unsigned char * to access &s.

It is possible to define a function that does not need a sequence point on return from the function, but that only applies to non-library functions defined with an empty body.

@IanAbbott While it is true that non-library functions need not have a sequence point at the end, there is always a sequence point after argument evaluation, before the function call.

The code is well-defined.
During assignment, the left and right operands of = are evaluated in an unsequenced manner. However (6.5.16 §3) "The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands."
Meaning we only need to worry about unsequenced scenarios if there are side effects on s.crc present in the function arguments. There aren't.
The side effect of updating s.crc is sequenced after the whole function call, as per the quoted part above. There is a sequence point after argument evaluation, before the function is called, and in addition likely several sequence points in the function itself.

Unrelated to that, it's going to be a very bad idea not to have the checksum (aka "FCS", frame check sequence) as the last member of the struct. Calculations assuming that the checksum is set to all zeroes/all ones etc also assume that the checksum itself is appended at the very end of the packet, since CRC is calculated with bitwise XOR from the start to the end.
Meaning that if you have a blank checksum with all zeroes, the CRC calculated checksum will end up in the end of the packet. But if you have a packet with CRC already calculated, then running the CRC algorithm on that whole packet including checksum field in the end should give you zero. And that won't happen with this very strange struct definition.
Also, it is a very bad idea to use some "sloppy typing" int for a CRC32. You should use uint32_t, period.
